# action method return null

Tags: t-sql, model-view-controller

In `VendorControllder` I have two methods ( one to display all and one to delete vendor)

```
// to display all vendor
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
            List<Vendor> Vlist = dbContext.Vendors.ToList();
            return View(Vlist);
        }

// to delete vendor 
 public ActionResult delv(Vendor VID) //this return null 
        {
            SLMEntitiesDB dbContext = new SLMEntitiesDB();
            dbContext.DelV(VID.VID);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

`DelV` is a procedure as below

```
create procedure [dbo].[DelV]
(@VID int)
as
begin
Delete from vendor where VID=@VID
end
```

from vendor Index I have two HTML Action link as below

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delv", new { VID = item.VID },null)
```

when i run the application, `VID` returns null

Comment: Please always add a tag that specifies the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: What programming language is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you ActionLink is set up incorrectly.
Change this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delv", new { VID = item.VID },null)
```

To this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "delv", "Vendor", new { VID = item.VID },null)
```

Remember the setup to an Html.ActionLink is: Link Text, Action Name, Controller Name, Route Values, Html Values